# How to do an ajax post of an image on an HTML page?

Tags: ajax, image, jquery, post

I'm using Alex Michael's fantastic javascript [filtrr library](http://alexmic.github.com/filtrr/)
to allow me to manipulate images on an HTML page. The question I have is how do I do an ajax/jquery post of an image that has been filtered inline on the page? For instance:

```
<div>
<img id="myimage" />
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="filterImage();" />
```

Once the filtering has been done, how do I post the contents of the image with id "myimage" back to a server-side PHP script so the filtered image can be saved? The tutorials I've seen for doing ajax image POSTs have all used file uploaders, which isn't what I'm looking for. I want to post an image from the HTML DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: then you need to access a desirable IMG via DOM and send CURRENT state of the one back to server side application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the library you are using uses the Canvas element, the solution here should apply:
[Uploading 'canvas' image data to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server)