# uploading canvas context as image using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, html, file-upload, canvas

I have a canvas and I want to upload the canvas context to the server using ajax and php. I want the final output to be an image stored on the server. I have done image uploading using form. But now I want to get the canvas context convert it to image and upload to the server!

So, how can i do that? Any suggestions, algos or solutions are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading 'canvas' image data to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This blog post](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/) aptly describes the method of saving canvases onto the server with AJAX queries, I guess this should be fitting for you.

Basically, you will need a `var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");` to retrieve the canvas' contents in JavaScript. This will be a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string, something like this: `data:image/png;base64,fooooooooooobaaaaaaaaaaar==`.

The following code will make sure the AJAX query sends the contents to the HTML:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData);
```

On the server, in the PHP script, you will have a key named `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` in the `$GLOBALS` array, this will contain the data we just fetched.

```
// Remove the headers (data:,) part.
$filteredData=substr($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'], strpos($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'], ",")+1);

// Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
$decodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

$fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $decodedData);
fclose( $fp );
```

Of course, `test.png` is the filename you will save. The first line is required to remove the `data:image/png;base64,` part of the encoded image, so that it can later be decoded by [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). It's output (`$decodedData`) will be saved to the file.

Comment: @MJQ [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) takes its `filename` argument, which might be a file path also. So if you change the `test.png` into `somefolder/test.png`, it will save into `somefolder` with the filename of `test.png`. Be careful as this method saves **ALL** files as `test.png`, essentially **overwriting** the previous save.

Comment: I'd recommend `file_get_contents('php://input')` over `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, IIRC the latter is not always populated.

Comment: @MJQ Happy to be able to help. :) Also, take the comment of @deceze into consideration too. You will need to modify `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']` to a variable like `$initialData` and give value to this variable with a `$initialData = file_get_contents('php://input');` at the **beginning** of the script. Or at least, _before_ the `$filteredData=...` line.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful Whisperity, thanks for that. I just came across a little problem with server side data handling via PHP: I had to set the content-type of my ajax-request to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and everything works as expected. Before doing that my image file was saved but was not able to open properly as an image.