# AJAX send a thing and PHP receive another thing?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, html5-canvas

I am using Fabric.js canvas library, and I want to save the canvas on the server.
Converted it into data URL:

```
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
```

and sent it to the server using Ajax:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "php/saveImg.php", true);
xhr.onload = () => {
if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
if (xhr.status === 200) {
let data = xhr.response;
window.open(data);
}}};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("canvasData=" + canvasData);
```

decoded the data and saved it in `saveImg.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['canvasData'])){
$imageData = $_POST['canvasData'];
echo $imageData;

$filteredData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",") + 1);
$a = file_put_contents( "images/image1.png", base64_decode($filteredData));
}
```

When I look into `image1.png`, it is transparent with nothing in it (yet it has the right dimensions and a size of 40 KB).

When I check the value that is received in `$_POST`, I can see that the value of the data is deformed: some `+` characters have been removed and some other chars have been added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uploading canvas context as image using ajax and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843115/uploading-canvas-context-as-image-using-ajax-and-php)

Comment: some other chars. Which chars can you share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST data is not encoded properly, you can use `encodeURIComponent` to do this

```
xhr.send("canvasData=" + encodeURIComponent(canvasData));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It solved the problem.