# Image upload with Canvas and Input file

Tags: html, file, canvas, input, upload

So before I get started, I will let you know that I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server) and mine is similar. Basically, i need to be able to have the user upload a file from the computer or take a picture from the webcam, put the photo on a canvas and upload that. Is there a way to change the source of a  using javascript (I want to change the file source to the to the dataURL)? Here is what I have so far.

In the main html page:

```
<form name="uploadFile" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"    onSubmit="return validate();">
<input type="file" id="imageupload" name="ufile" onKeyPress="return false;">(* jpg,png)
</form>
```

And in a seperate JS file I have:

```
button2.addEventListener('click', function(){
imgdata=canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$("#imageupload").attr("src", imgdata);
});
```

This code does do what is supposed to (it changes the attribute of #imageupload) but that is how to change the source of the file.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What language are using on the server? Also, are you editing the image on the canvas?