# Take a snapshot of a div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `<div>` with an image in it. The image can be resized by users input, also items can be added to the current image. Once finished I would like the user to be able to save this image they created.

I have used `MVC4` and `jQuery` to build the project. Is there anyway to save a snapshot of the created item? I have looked at canvas but this would not work in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Save a temporary snapshot locally for use again during user's 'current' session?

Comment: @Mark - Sorry I need to save this to a database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intriguing question:

You can start here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ a library that allows you to "copy" HTML into canvas.

Then, go here: [Uploading 'canvas' image data to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server)

An answer that shows you how to send the canvas image to the server.

There you have it.

Disclaimer: have not tried myself, but I'm now dying to. Work deadlines not allowing :)

Comment: Seems to work sort of, do you know if this can this be done on part of a screen and not the body?

Comment: I worked with this for some time. It CAN be done for a part of screen (a specific HTML element). You'll have to check the documentation. However I'd rather suggest you get the coordinate of resized image and other items and then do the processing server side. More reliable imo.