# How to download "image with a text added on it" on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a post maker web app, where you can add image and a text on it, now I want to add a download button to ***

> download image along with a text

*** on it.

i added `<img>` tag to add image , and a `<input type="textarea">` to achieve this.

Comment: By the way, there is no `type="textarea"` for inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add text on image using Javascript and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116851/how-to-add-text-on-image-using-javascript-and-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do that with an `<img>`
That said, you can use `<canvas>` and just save the finished canvas using JS:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 

window.location.href=image;
```