# How to add text dynamically text using both JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working with Canvas and I'm trying to add centered text dynamically on a picture.

I read on this topic ([How to add text on image using Javascript and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116851/how-to-add-text-on-image-using-javascript-and-canvas)), that I have to put some jQuery in my code. I tried but I did not succeed because I don't have a lot experience in jQuery.

```
You can find the example I made on the JSFiddle link below.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ParkerIndustries/t3rao9hL/14/

Comment: Sorry, the mistake was in the fillText function. If you want to center horizontally, put width/2 in fillText as x position. So ```context.textAlign = 'center';``` works but, I just set a bad position.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to add in jQuery to your code ( besides having the jquery.min file loaded ), you precursor any code with the "$" symbol and then the element you are identifying ( wrapped in parenthesis ). In your case:

```
 $(context)
```

since you've already identified your element. Then after that there are a couple ways to change css using jQuery.

```
$(context).css({ 'display', 'none' });
$(context).addClass('changed');
```

If you don't have an identifier, just put it in quotes:

```
$('#context').addClass('changed');
```

For JavaScript, Clarity answered that in the comment above.