# How would one create an image from a website using data from a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure what tags this would fall under so I apologise if the scope is too large! I'm currently trying to build a site where a user would write their name into a form and select a template to build on top of. The site would then generate an image of their name and put it over a specific box on the image template they selected.
If anyone has some suggestions on how I could approach this / resources that would help, I'd really appreciate it.

An example is posted below:

[image: simple design of what the form and creation process would entail]

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I personally disagree with what you posted, but I'll consider it next time.

Comment: I'm not saying that it was inappropriate of you to post your question. However, many people in the community do feel that questions should be specific and not too broad. In that respect, your question was, as far as I can tell, somewhat borderline. That is probably why you received one downvote (not from me, though). Therefore, I think it was important for you to read that link, so that you know where the community sets the limit and why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write and manipulate image in [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), use Imagick or [PHP GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).
I would recommend Imagick as it has more image formats and quality is better. But if you want fast rendering, use GD.

Using Javascript, you can use Canvas. Here is an example to use canvas to write on image [How to add text on image using JavaScript and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116851/how-to-add-text-on-image-using-javascript-and-canvas)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about Canvas - this has exactly what I need. Appreciate it.